# POST using multipart/form-data in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I need to essentially POST a local image to Cisco Webex room from my NodeJS service. For local files, you need to do a `multipart/form-data` request instead of JSON as mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.webex.com/attachments.html#local-file-attachments).

The CURL looks like

```
curl --request POST \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
  --form "files=@/home/desktop/example.png;type=image/png" \
  --form "roomId=Y2lzY2....." \
  --form "text=example attached" \
  https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages
```

But I am not sure how to convert it to nodeJS request format. I tried to use CURL to Node request converter [here](https://curl.trillworks.com/#node) but doesn't seem like it is handling the `multipart/form-data` type. Please suggest.

EDIT: after doing some research, I came up with the below code

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var params = { roomId: ROOMID,
    text: "hello....",
    files: {
       value: fs.createReadStream(PATH_WO_FILENAME),
       options: {
         filename: 'image.jpg',
         contentType: 'jpg'
       }
     }
   };
   var headersWebex = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_BOT_ACCESS_TOKEN',
       'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }



request.post({
         headers: headersWebex,
         url:     'https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages',
         method: 'POST',
         body:  params
       }, function(error, response, body){
         console.log(body);
       });
```

But it is throwing error

```
undefined
_http_outgoing.js:642
    throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
```

Comment: What does your code look like?  Express has a body-parser module which solves this for you, but who knows if you're using that server-side or not.

Comment: @Brad added the code

Comment: Have you seen this section in the request docs? It seems to cover this - https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads

Answer (score 2):

Ok so here is how I made it work. I essentially needed to look deeper into the [docs](https://github.com/request/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads) that @Evan mentioned

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var roomID = 'MY_ROOM_ID'
var params = {
  roomId: roomID,
  text: "hello....",
  files: {
    value: fs.createReadStream('./image.jpg'),
      options: {
      filename: 'image.jpg',
      contentType: 'image/jpg'
      }
    }
};

var headersWebex = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_BOT_ACCESS_TOKEN',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

request.post({
  headers: headersWebex,
  url: 'https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages',
  method: 'POST',
  formData: params
  }, function(error, response, body){
    if (error)
      console.log(error)

    console.log(body);
  });
```